# Cannot connect to PSQL with username and password

Tags: authentication, psql

When I start psql session, I just write 'psql' in my terminal and the session starts with the current user 'rashid'. Example below ---

```sh
$ psql
psql (12.9 (Ubuntu 12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

rashid=#
```

But when I try opening it with any DBMS tool like Datagrip or try connecting with a nodejs app, it shows auth_failed error.

In case of nodejs, the error looks like ----

```sh
error: password authentication failed for user "rashid"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/rashid/code/personal/nodejs-graphql/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:369:69)
    at Parser.handlePacket (/home/rashid/code/personal/nodejs-graphql/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:188:21)
    at Parser.parse (/home/rashid/code/personal/nodejs-graphql/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/parser.ts:103:30)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/rashid/code/personal/nodejs-graphql/node_modules/pg-protocol/src/index.ts:7:48)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  length: 102,
  severity: 'FATAL',
  code: '28P01',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'auth.c',
  line: '330',
  routine: 'auth_failed'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Kind of similar error is thrown by Datagrip as well. Please help me connect with my postgres Database :((